# How to order arguments in Prolog predicates for specifically for an exam question?

Tags: prolog

I am confused about ordering arguments in Prolog, for example a predicate like `between/3` that represents the relationship between 3 people sitting in an order (let's say Susan sits between Ali and John), the problem is should it be `between(Susan, Ali, John)` or `between(Ali, Susan, John)`?

**Please note that the `between/3` predicate is different from the built-in one, it's just an example.**

I expect it to be the first one, however in an exam I had -few days ago- it says that the correct answer is the second as Susan relies between the other two arguments. What I understands is if the predicate was `sit/3` it would be the second one, but for the `between/3` one Susan should come first as that's how we express predicates in Prolog (in their order in English) like if we want to express "Susan likes John" it would be `likes(Susan, John)` not `likes(John, Susan)`.

So what do you think the correct order should be? Please provide some clarification why you think so.

Comment: See https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/split-list/4836/8 - `between(Ali, John, Susan)` - it's not a 100% convention though, e.g. with `compare/3` the result is first, because it's more useful that way.

Comment: You can order them as you like. The correct answer to your exam questions is decided by your professor, not by popular opinion on Stackoverflow. "Please provide some clarification why you think so." hehe

Comment: @TA_intern I know about the exam, it's just about I could find nothing about arranging arguments in fact not about the exam itself.

Comment: @MahmoudIbrahim reading the answer that you have accepted, as well as your comments bellow it, I jump to the following conclusions: yes, you could have figured it out on your own, by looking at existing predicates; yes, it is a matter of opinion how to do it, so no strict rules nor unambiguous answers; and yes, after all, it seems to be about exam questions after all. Please provide clarification why you think so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at (mostly) built-in Prolog predicates, I see 4 main general conventions, which all have sensible reasons:

- Specified parameters, Object to act upon, Results - as per https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/split-list/4836/8
- First-argument indexing being useful, e.g. https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=compare/3
- Predicate named as per its argument order, e.g. https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=compound_name_arity/3
- "is a" predicates, e.g. `parent(mary, fred)` reads as "mary *is a* parent of fred"
- What feels natural, e.g. https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=succ/2 (contradicts the "is a" convention)

https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=between/3 has the reasonably standard order of the 2 required arguments (upper and lower limits) being specified first, and the (changeable upon backtracking) result being the last argument.

To my mind, given that `between/3` is well-known, it would be very odd if an exam question used the standard, built-in predicate of between/3 and *changed* the argument order.

Comment: thanks for your effort, I really appreciate this.
unfortunately, the question with the `between/3` predicate was repeated in 3 separate exams and maybe more and the only logical reason is that they don't really mean the built-in predicate at all.

Comment: I would complain - ask them to change their custom `between/3` to any name that isn't already a commonly built-in predicate.

Comment: yeah with this knowledge, I will do.